# To add multiple categories and subcategories in Magento

Tags: magento, categories, magento-1.9.1

I want to add as much as about 10 categories and about 30 to 40 of subcategories.
Is there any way of adding them in just one go except the manual one?
I also want to add subcategories of subcategories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my blog link hope it works for you

http://magento-rohan.blogspot.in/2014/07/magento-create-multiple-sub-category-in.html

Make sure you can change below code

1. $rootCateId - here you need to set the ID of root category under which you want to add sub categories
2. $path = here I set this as "1/2/" mostly in magento by default this is same but cross check it once.

And also create the csv file with list of categories named **category.csv**

let me know if it helps

Comment: you have to create a csv file having single column with title 'category' nothing else like 
"category"
cate_1
cate_2
cate_3
cate_4 etc